# Every open interval (a,b) with a < b is uncountable in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

So I want to show that a open interval ($a$,$b$) with 
$a$ $<$ $b$ is uncountable in $\mathbb{R}$.

My idea:
we can show that:

For $a$ ,$b$ , $c$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ the interval ($a$,$b$) is equipotent to ($a$+$c$,$b$+$c$). We can use this fact for the proof :

We know that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. Maybe we could $\mathbb{R}$ write as a countable union of intervals, which are equipotent to ($a$,$b$) ?

Comment: You can carry on with your idea; given any interval $(c,d)$ you can map $(a,b)$ bijectively onto $(c,d)$; It's sufficient to map $(a,b)$ to an interval of length $d-c$, and this can be done via a bijection $f(x)=\frac{d-c}{b-a}x$. So every open interval is equivalent (or equinumerous). But $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} (-n,n)$. If $(a,b)$ were countable, then $\mathbb{R}$ is countable

Answer (score 4):

The map $f:(a,b)\rightarrow{\bf{R}}$, $f(x)=\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{b-a}\left(x-\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)\right)$ is a bijection.

Comment: Indeed! One liner. Thank you. But I'm just curious. Is there another solution? What's about my idea?

Comment: Yes your idea goes through but I think we need the set theoretic cardinal arithmetic to deal with that.

Answer (score 2):

The function defined by
$$f(x)=\frac1{x-a}+\frac1{x-b}$$
is a bijection between $(a,b)$ and $\Bbb R$.

Alternatively, IMHO a quick hand-drawn "picture proof" is quite adequate: the function with the following graph is a bijection between $(a,b)$ and $\Bbb R$.

[image]

But you'll have to rotate it because I don't know how to :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Nice illustration & function :D . But I have a question: Do you think, that i can solve this with my attempt? ( i like it to have alternative solutions ) :)

Comment: Take $0<c<b-a$ and consider the union of all intervals $(a+kc,b+kc)$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$.  If the original interval is countable this will be a countable union of countable sets, therefore countable; but it will include $\Bbb R$ which is uncountable.  Contradiction.